# In the Twin Earth thought experiment, why doesnt "water" turn out to be a hypernym (parent term)?

Tags: sense-and-reference, hilary-putnam, externalism

**Background**
Putnam's Twin Earth thought experiment asks us to imagine a planet called Twin Earth, which is exactly like Earth except on Twin Earth their water is not H2O, but rather, XYZ. The substances are indistinguishable in every respect except for constitution. The inhabitants of both worlds use the sound "water" to refer to the substances on their respective planets. Additionally, the inhabitants of both worlds do not know the molecular composition of the liquid.

Putnam takes it that the inhabitants of these planets do not mean the same thing when they say "water".

**My thoughts**

In Putnam's example, I'd expect "water" to be a hypernym of the two substances.

An example to make the point:

If Earth's cars were made exclusively of aluminum and Twin Earth's were made exclusively of steel, the word "car" would seem to serve as a suitable sign for both. If I want to get more specific, I can say "steel car" or "aluminum car". Similarly, if I want to get more specific about the type of water I have in mind, I can specify H2O or XYZ.

I know that Putnam is a direct referentialist. So he probably believes that being causally related to the substances is important. So, to Putnam, Twin Earthers are causally related only to XYZ, and Earthers only to H2O.

But the same can be said about Earthers and Twin Earthers and steel cars and aluminum cars *but* the term "car" used by a person from either planet, would seem to convey the appropriate content just fine, even if he were speaking on the other planet. The extension of "car" would be the cars on both planets.

I think, for Putnam, natural kinds have some sort of special status (although, I can't imagine why he thinks they do; I'd be happy to learn the reason) Perhaps their status as natural kinds is what makes the difference for him here.

**Questions**

1. Why do Putnam and his sympathizers believe that the fact that the constitutions of the substances differ results in "water" having two meanings on each planet, rather than a single broader meaning that aligns with the intension, sense, or conceptualizations (and so on) of the users of the language?
2. Has anyone argued that "water" would serve as a hypernym for XYZ and H2O.

*Note: other twin earth questions have been asked, but not this one.*

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the significance of baptism is to this question, but if you're asking in a religious Christian context, see 1st Peter 3: "...God waited patiently in the days of Noah, during the building of the ark, in which [only the 8 people who were on the ark], were saved through water. And baptism, which this prefigured, now saves you—not as a removal of dirt from the body, but as an appeal to God for a good conscience, through the resurrection of Jesus Christ."

Comment: If Twin Earth is identical, then Twin Noah (or Twin ahistorical myth of Noah) was saved through Twin water during the Twin destruction and repopulation of Twin humanity in the Twin water of the Twin flood, so it would presumably prefigure appeals to Twin God through the resurrection of Twin Jesus using Twin water.

Comment: @gs "baptism" is a metaphor for the very first time a thing is named by a language community.

Comment: "*What the heck is 'water'?*" This is why we should not worship concepts.

Comment: One can very well use "water" as a hypernym, the point is that Putnam does not use it as such to make his point. There is no fact of the matter as to whether "water" is or is not a hypernym, there is nothing anywhere to discover that would settle it. Putnam has his definition of meaning and, on that definition, "water" has two meanings. That is what causal theory delivers. One can reject the definition and construct alternative theories of meaning, and then argue that they are "better" (which has been done extensively). But that involves comparing theories overall, not just in this scenario.

Comment: @Conifold yeah I suspected that's the case. I haven't seen anything yet from the semantic externalists that doesn't just assume the theory from the beginning. I had hoped their thought experiments might help with that (the SEP says that they're supposed to), but the consensus seems to be that that hope is misguided.

Comment: It might help in a more limited sense. Take a different theory and see how it deals with externalist scenarios, whether the explanations are more/less contrived, etc. Even if we interpret "water" as a definite description, say, the difference Putnam and others point out will not go away and has to be handled. Indeed, internalists had to make lengthy elaborations to account for it. And descriptivism has its own major difficulties elsewhere, as Kripke detailed. We have a messy set of intuitions about meaning and existing theories have to pick out different subsets to produce something coherent.

Comment: What difference is it that won't go away? The only issue I'm aware of is Kripke's about rigid designation across possible worlds and Aristotle possibly not being the teacher of Alexander the great (etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The thought experiment might have made sense in the 17th century, but it's nonsense in the 21st, when every high school graduate is supposed to have learned formulae like 6H2O+6CO2 <-> C6H12O4 + 6O2. It is impossible for Twin Earth to be just like Earth except for water - Twin Earth either has an identical glucose-and-oxygen metabolizing Putnam and water, or it has a non-identical Putnam who metabolizes XYcose and Zgen.

Comment: For the sake of the thought experiment, the XYZ chemistry might behave identically to the H₂O chemistry in every physical interaction that has yet occurred, but be distinguishable by some _\*waves hands\*_ black swan experiment.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 the point is not that we can't constitute a world such that it would be hard for them to tell whether it was water or not, the point is that such a world must necessarily be either identical to or completely different from our own, because part of what makes water water is what is the way in which it stops being water and becomes other things (in this example, chemical components for glucose and oxygen).

Comment: We could, for example, have Twin Earth being made out of antimatter. That would be easy to test being different if they were nearby, or even if there was any significant continuous matter distribution between here and there (look for gamma rays from annihilation!), but if they were a million light years away in the vast emptiness of intergalactic space and we decided (with a million year delay and a really really really bright signal) to tell them about water and ask them if they had water too...

Comment: ...They couldn't be 100% sure that they didn't have antiwater - but they would know that *if* they had antiwater, then they must be antipeople living on an antiplanet orbiting an antisun.

Comment: What if XYZ was made of Xotons and Yeutrons (made of XYuarks) and Zectrons and _\*waves hands\*_ the quantum physics calculations happened to come out the same _except_ for a specific family of experiments that distinguished them? And for _\*waves hands\*_ reasons, the XYZ-ness was concentrated in the water molecules, leaving everything else basically just regular matter? We're already positing a _duplicate Earth_, so why not posit Occam's Razor-defying laws of physics, too? We're trying to study the nature of language, not chemistry.

Comment: Talking about the molecular composition is a _framing device_, not a fundamental part of the argument.